# Rabin cryptosystem functions

Tags: php, math, cryptography

I'm trying to implement the [Rabin cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_cryptosystem) and I'm stuck the decryption step. I need to solve:

> Y<sub>p</sub> * p + Y<sub>p</sub> * q = 1

and calculate `Yp` and `Yq`, when `p` and `q` is known (given).

Let's take example from wikipedia, so `p = 7` and `q = 11`; We'll have then:
`Yp * 7 + Yq * 11 = 1;`

By using [extented Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) we should get the result:
`Yp = -3` and `Yq = 2`;

Here's pseudo code from Wiki:

```
//pseudo code
function extended_gcd(a, b)
if b = 0
    return (1, 0)
else
    (q, r) := divide (a, b)
    (s, t) := extended_gcd(b, r)
    return (t, s - q * t)
```

---

Here's what I've done so far:

```
//q = 11; p = 7;
$arr = array(11, 7); //test  number from wiki; 
$result = extendedGcd($arr); //output array(0,1)
                             //but should be: array(-3, 2); (from wiki example)
...
//Legend: arr[0] = a; arr[1] = b;   
function extendedGcd($arr){
    if ($arr[1] == 0) return array(1, 0);
    else{
        //( (q, r) := divide (a, b) ) == ( q := a div b, r = a − b * q );
        $q = floor($arr[0] / $arr[1]); $r = $arr[0] - $arr[1] * $q;
        $tmp = extendedGcd($arr[1], $r); 
        $s = $tmp[0]; $t = $tmp[1];
        return array($t, $s - $q * $t);
    }
}
```

I don't know what's wrong. how can I calculate Yp and Yq?

---

Solved. 
If someone looks for it in PHP:
Recursive method:

```
//thank to NullUserException ఠ_ఠ
function extendedGcd($arr){
 if ($arr[1] == 0) return array(1, 0);
 else{
    $q = floor($arr[0] / $arr[1]);
    $r = $arr[0] % $arr[1];
    $temp = extendedGcd(array($arr[1], $r));
    $s = $temp[0]; $t = $temp[1];
    return array($t, $s - $q * $t);
 }
}
```

Non-recursive. (Iknow it looks ugly, still it works.

```
function extendedGcd($a, $b){
 $x = 0;    $lastx = 1;
 $y = 1;    $lasty = 0;
 while ($b != 0){ //while b ≠ 0
    $quotient = floor($a / $b);
    $tempA = $a; $a = $b; $b = $tempA % $b;
    echo '<br />$a = '.$a.'; $b = '.$b;
    echo '<br />$quotient = '.$quotient;
    $tempX = $x;
    $x = $lastx - $quotient * $x;
    $lastx = $tempX;
    $tempY = $y;
    $y = $lasty - $quotient * $y;
    $lasty = $tempY;       
    echo '<br />$lastx = '.$lastx.'; $lasty = '.$lasty.'<hr />'; 
 }
 return array($lastx, $lasty);
}
```

Comment: Please share your whole class and some example data, so it's easier to follow what you've done so far.

Comment: @hakre, ediited. Hope it'll help. Code here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/X5Ng6v

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann
Nothing? :) http://codepad.viper-7.com/VozX2M
Or i've misunderstood you?

Comment: I also tried non-recursive method out of there (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). http://codepad.viper-7.com/0CopdP
No success still. Could 2 of algorithm be wrong? Any idea?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I did a mistake (`1` instead of `-1`) in my pen-and-pager implementation of the algorithm where I tried to try it, and thus came to (0,1) myself in the result, and thus said "Wikipedia is wrong". Correcting this mistake, I get (2,-3), which seems to fit (2·11-3·7 = 1). NullUserException got the real problem in his answer.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer (and accept it then). This will help to make this site working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was that you were calling `extendedGcd()` like this: `extendedGcd($arr[1], $r);`, when it actually only took a single argument (an array). Here's how I would rewrite the function:

```
function extendedGcd($a, $b){
    if ($b == 0) 
        return array(1, 0);

    $q = floor($a / $b); 
    $r = $a % $b;        // PHP does have a modulus operator

    list($s, $t) = extendedGcd($b, $r); 
    return array($t, $s - $q * $t);
}

print_r(extendedGcd(11, 7));
```

Which gives you [the result expected](http://codepad.org/xxqnDwCO).

---

PS: In the process of testing the correctness of the algorithm, I used this Python function:

```
def extended_gcd(a, b):
    if b == 0:
       return (1, 0)

    else:
        (q, r) = (a/b, a%b)
        (s, t) = extended_gcd(b, r)
        return (t, s - q * t)
```

Hauntingly beautiful, isn't it?

Comment: Yep, i got it right now, rewritten. Ugly but works. http://codepad.viper-7.com/teKN5X 
Oh. sorry haven't read your post. Will try it now. Thank you.

Comment: @ted I further updated my answer; the recursive approach should work just fine too.

Comment: @ted: You can use `list($s, $t) = extendedGcd($b,r$)` to avoid the temporary array in PHP, too.